# Add Finder Sidebar Section via Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, bash

**Is it possible to add a new section to the Finder sidebar?**

I'm interested in adding a new section to the Finder sidebar, and auto-populating it as part of some personal automation.

I understand that the existing sections can be configured by using `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to modify `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`.

Is this something a UI/Applescript/Bash/Zsh can do? If so, how? Or would this require something more involved such as Swift/Obj code?

Comment: In **Finder**, **Sidebar** _items_, such a items shown under, e.g., **Favorites**, are not stored in **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist**, and if I recall correctly never were. Looking at the system I'm current on, **macOS High Sierra**, **Favorites** on the **Sidebar** in **Finder** are stored in **~Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2**. -- As to: "Is it possible to add a new section to the Finder sidebar?" -- I do not believe it is possible to add you own _section_, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: That would be unfortunate, as an aside, I have favourites set but that file/folder does not exist on my machine ( Catalina )

Comment: **~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2** does not exist by default; however, the first time **Favorites** in **Finder** > **Preferences…** > **Sidebar** are changed, or the user adds to the **Sidebar**, then the _file_ is created.

Comment: Nope, i already have items in my sidebars favourites, and I made changes to it, neither that folder or file exist or were created. It might be the case for you, but it is not the case in Catalina

Comment: On a clean install of **macOS Catalina 10.15.4** that file does exist on my system. It was created when I added a _folder_ to the **Sidebar** under **Favorites**. Why it doesn't exist on your system I can't say, other then do you know that **~/Library** is hidden by default and maybe that's why you're not seeing it?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what's going on then, I think there's more logic to this than what either of us know, I used the terminal to check for the folder